# How do I delete an object?

Tags: modeling

I want to delete an object. So I press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button and then a menu pops up and I select vertices. But then the object still appears in the outliner. I still see "cube' there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to delete from object from *Object Mode*, not *Edit Mode*. You can switch between *Object Mode* and *Edit Mode* using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key on your keyboard. You can also switch using he drop down menu on the bottom panel of the 3d View window.Then hit delete again (Function delete on Mac) and you will be able to <kbd>Delete</kbd> the object entirely, it will also disappear from the outliner. If you want to delete parts of your mesh use *Edit Mode*, if you want to delete the entire mesh use *Object Mode*.

Switch to *Object Mode*

[image]

Now you can delete

[image]

Comment: On my MacBook hitting `delete` didn't do anything, but as you can see in the screenshot. The other hotkey is `X`, which worked.

Comment: "now you can delete" Do we press a key (delete key doesn't seem to work, or use a menu, edit>delete?)

Answer (score 14):

[Deleting in *Edit mode*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Basics/Deleting) only deletes the geometry elements of the object. Other data (Modifiers, location, rotation, etc.) is still there.

To delete an *object*, you need to delete in [*Object mode*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects).

1. Set the [mode](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Modes) to object mode. There are two ways to do this:

   - Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> toggles [*Edit mode*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes). (Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> while in *Edit mode* switches to the last mode used before *Edit mode*)
   - Directly setting the mode to *Object* from the menu in the *3D view > Header*:

     [image]
2. Select the object you want to delete and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd>*> Delete*:

   [image]

For more information about modes, see the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Modes):

> Modes are a Blender-level object-oriented feature, which means that
>   the whole Blender application is always in one and only one mode, and
>   that the available modes vary depending on the selected active
>   object’s type – most of them only enable the default Object mode (like
>   cameras, lamps, etc.). Each mode is designed to edit an aspect of the
>   selected object. See the Blender’s Modes table below for details.

Comment: I like your answer but you include too much information  .

Comment: @Yppie Actually, the information provided is quite important. In Blender, the object-mesh distinction can be very useful or a total headache depending on whether or not you understand it.

Comment: There should be some kind of in-app usage tutorial which comes with Blender and automatically runs everytime you've gone more than a month without using it. Because I forget the basics like this every freaking time (Blender is not my day job. Sometimes I just need a rough model and I need it right freaking now for whatever I'm working on, so I don't have time to ask someone else to make it, so I fire up blender and struggle with the basics for 2 hours.)

Comment: I still can't delete he default cube, and i'm in Object Mode. Anything else I need to check for?

Comment: @user23775 is the cube the active object (white outline)? Right click objects to make them active

Answer (score -1):

In 2021, the answer is to go into *Object Mode* and hit *X*, not the *Delete* key.

Comment: Welcome to Blender's Stack Exchange. The option to delete the object from object mode with the x-key has already been explained in the accepted answer. Please try to avoid posting duplicate answers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Delete key does delete objects, even in the latest version (2.92)

Comment: Correct, the delete key still works. The difference is x-key asks for confirmation, delete-key doesn't.

Comment: Maybe it's just a problem specific to my M1 arm64 build. Not sure why my Delete key isn't working for 2.94 alpha.