# Deleting an object from the outliner

Tags: interface

[image: Scene layers]

Not sure of correct term, but, how do you delete a layer such as the 'body' layer.

[image: (244) Lamp)]

Once again, not sure of correct name for this, but the (244) should read (1). How is this deleted or changed?

Comment: The (244) is the current frame actually :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a layer view even tho it looks like one if you are coming from other software. The view you are looking at is called the [Outliner](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/outliner.html) and those are objects in your scene. To delete an object in Blender, you can go the the 3d view, select it and use the <kbd>X</kbd> key. From the outliner, right click the entry and choose *Delete*. Further reading — [How do I delete an object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3467/how-do-i-delete-an-object)

Answer (score 1):

That is the frame number in the bottom left corner of the 3D view. It is just telling you what the current frame is.

You can use any means of changing the frame to change that display: timeline, graph editor, dope sheet, etc.
The fastest way to return to frame one is to press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>.

---

You can disable the display of the current frame in the user preferences.
In the *Interface* tab uncheck the box for *Object Info*, that will hide the active object's name and current frame.
[image: user preferences]

Answer (score 0):

Blender 2.8:

1. Blender Preferences > Keymap > Outliner
2. Find Delete Collection  — with Backspace
3. Change command to `object.delete`, uncheck ‘Confirm’

[image: Delete image from outliner with one keypress]

Select an object in outliner and press Backspace. Super fast. A default option did require two clicks: right click and select Delete.
You can still delete a collection pressing the `X` (another default keymap in Blender).

Note: The object shouldn't be hidden.