# How do I delete an object? (Like a cylinder)

Tags: objects

I have looked through a few posts on deleting objects (namely How do I delete an object by Yppie), but they wont work for me.

[How do I delete an object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3467/how-do-i-delete-an-object)

I have a cylinder that I accidentally created. Normally, I would work it into the character or setting, but I cant seem to find a place to put it. (Except the nose, but I'm creating the legs right now so it will take a while.) So how do I delete it?

Comment: Please clarify what didn't work for you with deleting. It's hard to understand what does second paragraph have to do with problem of deleting an object. Delete object in the mode appropriate for you; if you'd like to delete part of mesh, select and delete in Edit mode; if whole object - in Object mode.

Comment: Objects are base entities, if you use the term 'object' it means you are in object mode. If you want to delete parts of an object that you added in edit mode then you are talking about the 'mesh'. There are many commands for selecting parts of a mesh that you want to delete, just try the 'select' menu and see what it has to offer, most useful in your case is 'select linked', then you delete it with X.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a mesh is fraught with danger! Depending upon the active mode, Blender allows you to add a mesh as its own object in object mode, or in edit mode to add the same mesh as part of another object. If a mesh is added in object mode, there are ate least two ways to delete it: find the object in the outliner window, select it, and using the context menu, delete it, or select the object in the 3D viewport, and delete it there using one of the means to delete objects in the 3D viewport.

On the other hand, if the mesh was added in edit mode by mistake, it is a bit harder. Then you have to select the object, click into edit mode, select an element of the mesh you want to delete, either a vertex, edge, or face, expand the selection to the whole of the mesh (one way is by pressing the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>), and deleting the selected vertices.

One other factor to complicate matters further: if you added an a mesh in object mode, and delete the vertices in edit mode as described above, you delete the vertices, but not the object, so in object mode you will still see the object's location, even though if there are no vertices to form a mesh.